# How to remove word which i connect with special character in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have qeustion for you ! How to remove all words containing @, such as @AmericanVirgin. When I do

```py
df['text'] = df ['text'].Str.replace('@', '') only removes @
```

This is my dataframe :

```
weet_id airline_sentiment   text    Raiting
0   570306133677760513  neutral @VirginAmerica What @dhepburn said. 2
1   570301130888122368  positive    @VirginAmerica plus you've added commercials t...   3
2   570301083672813571  neutral @VirginAmerica I didn't today... Must mean I n...   2
```

This is outopu after answer
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input :

```
tweet_id             airline sentiment  \
0         0  570306133677760513   neutral   
1         1  570301130888122368  positive   
2         2  570301083672813571   neutral   

                                          text  Raiting  \
0           @VirginAmerica What @dhepburn said        2   
1  @VirginAmerica plus youve added commercials        3   
2                @VirginAmerica I didn't today        0
```

```
# Using regex, removing words starting with @
dframe["text_corrected"] = dframe.text.str.replace("@\w+\s", "")
```

Output :

```
tweet_id             airline sentiment  \
0         0  570306133677760513   neutral   
1         1  570301130888122368  positive   
2         2  570301083672813571   neutral   

                                          text  Raiting  \
0           @VirginAmerica What @dhepburn said        2   
1  @VirginAmerica plus youve added commercials        3   
2                @VirginAmerica I didn't today        0   

                  text_corrected  
0                     What  said  
1   plus youve added commercials  
2                 I didn't today
```

Comment: You are right, I added \s at the end of the regex expression.

Comment: When im using df["text"] = df.text.str.replace("@\w+\s", "")  i got like these weet_id airline_sentiment text Raiting
0 570306133677760513 neutral VirginAmericaWhatdhepburnsaid. I need remove each word which is start @

Comment: you used "\w" lower case not upper case "\W" ?

Comment: yes, used lower i had changed picture on my post

Comment: Please recheck with this 
```
dframe.text.str.replace("@\w+\s", "", regex=True)
```

Comment: You can open your notepad+ and type this sentence : "@VirginAmerica What @dhepburn said" then Ctrl+F, select use regex, and the put "\@\w+\s"  you should be able to select the words starting with @ and the last space.

Comment: still nothing after Regex=True. When i put on notepad \@\w+\s i can find @VirignAmerica. So you know how to fix it ?

Comment: Could you explain me also how to know , how to use @\w+\s ? what is \w \s

Comment: \w means you are looking for a word.
\s means you are looking for one space.
+ is a quanti­fier, it means 1 of the previous symbol or more.
Here is an interesting cheat sheet : 
https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/